# How to disable MenuBar in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have a MenuBar in my app and need to disable that based on some condition.
The setEnabled(boolean) method is not available on GWT MenuBar hence there is no straight way to go ahead with this requirement.

For Ex: If you look into `NestedAnchor.setEnabled(boolean enabled)` it disables the events on that widget and adds a style too.
I would like to do the same behavior on MenuBar where click events are not triggered to show the popup.

Also tried with jquery to add `disabled` attr, still no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will serve the purpose : `menuBar.unsinkEvents(Event.MOUSEEVENTS | Event.ONCLICK | Event.FOCUSEVENTS | Event.KEYEVENTS);`

Comment: This disables the events getting fired on the menu bar. Well interesting but what about the styles ???? I think you can achieve your purpose in a more easy way.... have a look at the answer provided by me.

Comment: Ya styling needs to be handled separately :)

Answer (score 2):

Menu bar is a container for menu items. Containers don't support disable property. So yohu have to manually iterate over the menu items list to disable each of them. Below code snippet does that by adding setEnable method to the Menu Bar -

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar()
{
         public void setEnable(boolean enableFl)
         {
              for( MenuItem item : getItems() )
              {
                    item.setEnable( enableFl );
              }
         }
};
```

Comment: This is the easiest and safest way of disabling the Menu Bar.

Comment: but this will still fire the click on MenuBar so that user can see the popup screen...but I do not want that too. Whats use of showing popup when all MenuItems are disabled?

Comment: If you are talking about the Menu Bar which gets opened on item click, then Menu bar should be shown with all items disabled. Otherwise user will get confused when he sees item with enabled style and not performing anything on click of it.

Comment: thats right, not to confuse the user, the menubar style needs to changed separately. The way  I said above will not open up popup window of menubar and moreover styling can be handled.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your menubar invisible

```
menuBar.setVisible(false);
```

When ever you want to enable menubar then menuBar.setVisible(true);

or

if you want disable style then add styleDisable in .css file and set style to

```
menuBar.setStyleName(styleDisable);
```

`then check style`

```
if(menuBar.getStyleName().equals("styleDisable")){

// write code here
}
```

Comment: @Satya to disable popup of menu bar add check condition like above, i thnk it will wrk, did u tried?

Comment: +1,The first one is pretty bad to hide the menu bar ,when you need to disable .But  the second one is a better solution .  :)

Comment: @TheSureshAtta i just told both bcz Satya can select any thing

Comment: :) I appreciate your efforts. Obviously he will choose second one .Because he wants to disable only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Api

```
DOM.setElementPropertyBoolean(menubar.getElement(), "disabled", !enabled);
```

Comment: this ll just add disabled property to the menuBar, thats what even jquery is applying but not disabling the popup of MenuBar

Comment: wrap the menu bar in a focusPanel, and use the above statement on the wrapper. It will definitely work.